# Insert data into a ClickHouse table from a file with deduplication

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I'm importing data into a ClickHouse table from CSV files.

```
cat data.csv | clickhouse-client --config-file=config.xml --query="INSERT INTO data_pool FORMAT CSVWithNames"
```

Often CSV files contain duplicate entries that are already in the ClickHouse table. What is the most efficient way to insert new data from a CSV file, skipping the entries already in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```bash
cat data.csv | clickhouse-client --echo --mn --config-file=config.xml --query="CREATE TABLE tmp_data_pool LIKE data_pool ENGINE=ReplcaingMergeTree() ORDER BY f1,f2,f3...fieldN; INSERT INTO tmp_data_pool FORMAT CSVWithNames; INSERT INTO data_pool SELECT * FROM tmp_data_pool FINAL; DROP TABLE tmp_data_pool SYNC"
```

look details about FINAL and ReplcacingMergeTree()
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree/

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#max-final-threads
and
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/19375

to improve FINAL performance optimizations

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not actually solve my problem. The main issue is to skip the duplicates from CSV that are already in the data_pool table.

The table data_pool can have the following:
```
col1   col2      col3
2       city2     value2
3       city3     value3
```
and the CSV file can have the following:

```
col1   col2      col3
0      city0      value0
2       city2     value2
4       city4     value
```

So I want to import from the CSV only two entries that are not in the data_pool:
```
0      city0      value0
4      city4      value
```

Comment: ok. after create TEMPORARY TABLE 
you can try do following query

`INSERT INTO table SELECT t1.* FROM tmp_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.col1=t1.col1 AND ... t1.colN  = t2.colN WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL SETTINGS join_use_nulls=1, join_algorithm='auto'`